# Running an *.exe file as administrator in NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I am trying to run an exe application as part of my NSIS Installer script. I am using EXEC command to run the application. The application runs but not as administrator. My application is changing some registry values, hence it has to run as administrator. The OS are Win 7 and above.

Exec '"$INSTDIR\bin\UserPasswordUtility.exe" $R0 $R1'

I am taking username($R0) and password($R1) as user inputs

I have requested execution level for admin
RequestExecutionLevel admin

I searched online. I could not find any answers.

Thank you

Comment: Is UAC turned on? Does UAC request elevation when you run the installer?

Comment: Yes UAC is turned on.

Comment: *Sigh*, Does UAC request elevation when you run the installer?

Comment: No I have not done UAC request elevation in my script

Comment: If you have "RequestExecutionLevel admin" in your .nsi then you are requesting elevation!

Answer (score 4):

If your custom application always requires UAC elevation then you should add a [RequestedExecutionLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929) node to its manifest. In NSIS you must use `ExecShell` to execute applications that require elevation, `Exec` cannot elevate.

If your application does not normally require elevation but you need to request it one time you can use the *runas* verb:

```
ExecShell "runas" "$sysdir\calc.exe"
```

If your installer always needs to execute a elevated application then you should probably request elevation for your installer as well with `RequestExecutionLevel admin` in your script.